# Question about p.adjust in R and BH correction

Tags: hypothesis-testing

In multiple test we adjust the significant level by BH. I used p.adjust in R and adjust my p value after that when I print those out it has some 0 and 1, I don’t get what it means .Also, does p.adjust default 0.05 significant level? In my knowledge, BH should change the significant level instead of p value, so I am confused

Comment: I assume soley 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for p.adjust there is this for "value"

> A numeric vector of corrected p-values (of the same length as p, with
> names copied from p).

So, it is doing what it says it should. Of course, p values can't be below 0 or above 1. The 0's are probably some sort of rounding or display problem.